# MySQL return output in empty set

Tags: mysql, is-empty

I have `movie` as my table

I tried to execute the following queries where put in 2 conditions with `movie_genre='comedy'` and  `movie_genre='family'`:

```
select movie_title, movie_cost, movie_genre
from movie
where movie_genre ='comedy'
and movie_genre ='family'
order by movie_cost asc;
```

After executed the queries it return `Empty set`.
While I tried one condition it works normally but when adding 2 conditions it goes wrong again.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `OR` to check if `movie_genre` is either of the two values.

Updated query -

```
select movie_title, movie_cost, movie_genre from movie
where movie_genre ='comedy' or movie_genre ='family'
order by movie_cost asc;
```

Comment: Well, typically you'd use IN()

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT movie_title, movie_cost, movie_genre
FROM movie
WHERE
   movie_genre ='comedy'
OR 
   movie_genre ='family'
ORDER BY movie_cost ASC;
```

You should use `OR` because `AND` means that the two conditions must be true at the very same time, but that's impossible!

A different query syntax could be

```
SELECT movie_title, movie_cost, movie_genre
FROM movie
WHERE movie_genre IN ('comedy', 'family')
ORDER BY movie_cost ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is UNION ALL:

```sql
SELECT movie_title, movie_cost, movie_genre
FROM movie
WHERE movie_genre = 'comedy'
UNION ALL
SELECT movie_title, movie_cost, movie_genre
FROM movie
WHERE movie_genre = 'family'
ORDER BY movie_cost ASC;
```